# .NET SCSS File And BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sass

I have an MVC4 application and the style sheet has been written in SASS/SCSS. I Am using the Web.Optimizations Library to Bundle all the CSS and JS Files. This works correctly, until I enable the EnableOptimizations property on the Bundle Table to compress all these files.

When rendering the site with this options all of the SASS file contents is missing and the site is not styled correctly, set the property back to false and all is well and site looks as it should.

The NuGet Packages I installed to the project that i think are relevant are as follows
Bundle Transformer: Core
Bundle Transformer: Sass and SCSS
Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework.

Here is a copy of my BundleConfig Class

```
 public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));



            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/assets/js").IncludeDirectory("~/assets/js","*.js",true));

            // "~/assets/css/styles.css",
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include("~/assets/css/cookiecuttr.css",
                                                               "~/assets/sass/styles.scss"));

            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So I have been working with this further, and have determined that the issue is mostly my use of the SCSS file. If i replace the SCSS file with a standard CSS file everything works correctly. I have also noticed that the SCSS file itself has no icon next to the file. perhaps I am missing some sort of support? I will keep looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved the issue,

Firstly installed NSASS.Core, NSASS.Handler and NSASS.Optimization, separated out the SCSS file to its own SASS Bundle. Added the render to the layout file, and enabled optimization true and it works.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to added the render to the layout file?  Did do something like `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/sass")`, referencing your `SassBundle`?

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't realize the `NSass.Handler` package was required when `<compilation debug="true" />` in Web.config, since the *.scss file is exposed, and not the compiled *.css.